# Call to local api does not work in the browser but shows success status with Postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I am creating an image generation website with Mern. One of my functions named handleSubmit, calls for a local API. The API is not fetched when running in the browser but runs fine when tested with Postman.

---

Below given is the frontend code for the function that call the API

```
    const handlesubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.prompt && form.photo) {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            body: JSON.stringify(form),
          },
        });
        await response.json();
        console.log("Hello");
        navigate("/");
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };
```

This is the code for the API backend.

```
import express from 'express'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import  {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary'
import Post from '../mongodb/models/post.js'

dotenv.config()


const router = express.Router()

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
  });

router.route('/').get(async(req,res) => {
    try{
        console.log("Hello")
        const posts = await Post.find({})
        res.status(200).json({success: true , data:posts})
    } catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({success: false , message:error})
    }
})
router.route('/').post(async(req,res) => {
    try {
        console.log("Hello")
        const { name, prompt, photo } = req.body;
    const photoUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(photo);

    const newPost = await Post.create({
      name,
      prompt,
      photo: photoUrl.url,
    });
    res.status(200).json({success:true, data:newPost})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({success:false , message:error})
    }
})

export default router
```

I did research and found that this issue was related to CORS, but I am not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body is inside the headers. You should take it out like:

```
 const handlesubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.prompt && form.photo) {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(form),
        });
        await response.json();
        console.log("Hello");
        navigate("/");
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Had been on this for 3 days 

Comment: @AditRamdas glad it helped! You can click the check mark to approve the answer and help other people see it